# How to get all the variables that were added to any constraint in a Solver?

Tags: z3, z3py

I am using Z3py and trying to get the set of all the variables in any constraint in a Solver. I can call `Solver.assertions()` to get an `ASTVector`, then loop over this vector and get objects of type `BoolRef`, for example, but then I'm stuck. How can I recursively iterate over an assertion, a `BoolRef` instance for example, to get the individual variables?

Comment: The set of variables/declarations exists inside the Solver, although the last I checked, it is not visible outside the C/C++ APIs (see, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054054/parse-smt-lib2-string-using-declarations-in-existing-context ).  Unless that's changed, an alternative is to just keep track of all the variables/declarations you've used yourself, then you'll have all of them available.  If you want to go the recursive route instead, there are methods to walk the AST: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236450/substituting-function-symbols-in-z3-formulas/15237285#15237285

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Taylor for your answer. I think the second link addresses the question.
In more detail, the python script that Leo added in the previous answer walks an AST, the AstMap ensures that shared sub-expressions are only walked once.